# Angular 2: Suppressing Origin Header from being sent

Tags: javascript, http, angular, cors, http-post

In my Angular2 application, I am making an HTTP call using the HTTP service that Angular2 provides. I see that the request that it sends contain the header `'Origin'`, with a value. Can someone please tell me if there is anyway we can prevent Angular2 from appending the Origin header to the HTTP request?

Comment: I believe the browser actually controls this header, if you're trying to perform a HTTP call [across domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), this header will be added.The [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Headers-class.html) show that there is a delete method you can call. I'm just not sure it will work as the browser is driving that header.

Comment: why? It's required for CORS requests and if it's local why would you care?

Comment: I am running Angular2, inside Electron. So, whenever I am making a PUT/POST request to another domain, it sends 'Origin' header with the value- 'file://'.

Comment: Should tag this question electron then and update question with specifics of problem it creates. Could try using an httpInterceptor to remove it

Comment: browser adds "Origin" header in case of  cross domain ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the server code to allow from your current origin, you can leverage the fact that Electron is running on top of node.js. You will want to add something like [Express](https://expressjs.com/) to your node.js/electron setup, that will act as a proxy between your XMLHttpRequests from Angular 2 and your server. So your http route will be (Angular 2 Http) => Express => Server.